# Is this graph connected

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, infinite-graphs

Define the following graph on the vertex set ${\mathbb N}_{\geq1}\>$:

Two numbers $a$, $b\in {\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ are connected by an edge (written  $a \ \mathcal{R} \ b)$ if and only if $a+b \ | \ ab-1$.

Clearly $1$ is isolated. Can we connect all integers greater than $2$ to $2$?
For example: $$2014 \ \mathcal{R} \ 147 \ \mathcal{R} \ 4175 \ \mathcal{R} \ 3891 \ \mathcal{R} \ 142 \ \mathcal{R} \ 43 \ \mathcal{R} \ 7 \ \mathcal{R} \ 3 \ \mathcal{R} \ 2.$$ Therefore $2014$ can be connected to $2$ (written $2014\sim2$).

> **Question**: Is this graph connected?

*Motivation :*

I worked on the [Machin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) and I wondered if we had $$\arctan \frac{1}{a} + \arctan \frac{1}{b} = \arctan \frac{1}{c}$$ where $a,b,c$ are integers and this happens if  $c=\frac{ab-1}{a+b}$ is an integer.

EDIT : My apologie I forgot to mention that the graph is restricted to positive integer.

Comment: Do you think it is important that we know what $\mathcal{R}$ means?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon sorry. Edited

Comment: I think the question can be rewritten as "Is every integer $n \geq 2$ in the transitive clausure of $\mathcal{R}$?"

Comment: It's not an equivalence relation.  It's not reflexive: $2$ is not related to $2$.  It's also not transitive: $2 \mathcal{R} 3 \mathcal{R} 7$ but $2$ is not related to $7$.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don't get it. Can you expand a little bit ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use negative integers, or is this graph only on positive integers?

Comment: An [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) satisfies three properties: reflexive, symmetric, transitive.  $\mathcal{R}$ is symmetric, but is neither reflexive nor transitive, and thus is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: Note that the OP asks about connectedness of a graph, apparently meaning one whose edges are between positive integers which satisfy $(a+b)|(ab-1)$.  That this is a symmetric relation means the graph is undirected for this purpose, and the absence of self-edges or transitive "triangles" on adjacent edges is not an impediment to asking about the connected components of the graph.

Comment: @hardmath She's probably objecting to the first sentence of the post "Define the following equivalence relation". It should be edited.

Comment: Okay, I'm confident this doesn't change the OP's meaning.

Comment: No, $R$ is not the equivalent relation, and the OP did not claim as such. $~$ is indeed an equivalent relation. Just like "adjacent" is not an equivalent relation, but "in the same connected component" is an equivalent relation.

Comment: we always have the chain $2n$,  $4n²-2n+1$, $4n²+2n+1$, $2n+1$.

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer :

We have $a \sim b$ if and only if there exist a sequence of integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ such that  $a \ \mathcal{R} \ a_1 \ \mathcal{R} \ \cdots \ \mathcal{R} \ a_n \ \mathcal{R} \ b$. The relation $ ab-1 = c (a + b) $ can be written as $(a-c)(b-c)=c^2+1$ and can be solves $a=c+d$ and $b=c+ \dfrac{c ^ 2 + 1} d$ where d is a divisor of $c^ 2 +1$.

If $c$ is even: All divisors of $c^2+1$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ then $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $4$.

If $c$ is odd: $d$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ and $\dfrac{c^2}d+1$ is congruent to $2$ modulo 4 or vice versa.
If $c=4k+1$ then $a$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$ and $b$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ or vice versa.
If $c = 4k +3$ then $a$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$ and $b$ to $1$ modulo $4$ or vice versa.

Therefore there is probably three components in the graph (but I did not prove this):

The first formed only by $1$, the second one formed by integer congruent to $0$ modulo $4$ or $1$, and the last by integer congruent to $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: is $(a-c)(b-c)=c^2+1$ I guess

Comment: @user126154 Thanks. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as CW because my "clarification" as to positive integers vs. integers generally being the domain/nodes got edited out (perhaps accidentally), and I wanted to show that without the restriction to positive integers, $1$ is not "isolated" as the Q asserts.

Let $R(a,b)$ mean $(a+b)|(ab-1)$ for integers $a,b$.  Then:

$$ R(1,0) \text{ since } (1+0)|(0-1) $$

$$ R(0,-1) \text{ since } (0-1)|(0-1) $$

$$ R(2,-1) \text{ since } (2-1)|(-2-1) $$

So this evidence points to restricting the graph to edges between positive integers.

Comment: @FreeX:  You're obviously engaged with this Question, since you offered the bounty.  Why not clarify the point, first raised above in Commenting on the Q by Calvin Line, whether the graph is restricted to positive integer nodes?

Comment: Sure, Sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but the following reformulation may lead to some inspiration.

For given $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ let $c=a+b$. Then adjacency between $a$ and $b$ may be written as $ab\equiv 1$ mod $c$. But $b\equiv -a$ mod $c$, so we also have $a^2=b^2=-1$ mod $c$. This suggests we should consider for what moduli we can solve $x^2=-1$ i.e. for which $-1$ is a quadratic residue.

If the modulus $p$ is an odd prime, then we have the classical result that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ iff $p\equiv 1$ mod 4. If $p=1$ mod 8 there is no simple expression for $x$, but if $p=5$ mod 8 then $x=2^{(p-1)/4}$ solves the congruence. Therefore if we choose $a\equiv 2^{(p-1)/4}$ for $0\leq a<p$ then $a$ and $p-a$ adjacent.

Hence the primes that equal 5 mod 8  generate a family of such adjacencies. By recalling other properties of the square root of -1 for various moduli, we can presumably generate other such families of adjacencies, and (optimistically) classify all adjacencies in a systematic way.

Answer (score -2):

If you told me to find for a given set. $c$ - integer of any sign.

Then for the equation.  $$\frac{ab-1}{a+b}=c$$

using factorization. In the following manner.

$$(k-n)(k+n)=4(c^2+1)$$

Then the solutions are.

$$a=c+\frac{k+n}{2}$$

$$b=c+\frac{k-n}{2}$$

$$.........$$

$$a=c-\frac{k+n}{2}$$

$$b=c-\frac{k-n}{2}$$